# How do I share a directory between an LXC container and the host?

Tags: mount, virtualization, symbolic-link, lxc

How can I share a folder between the host system (ubuntu 14.04) and an ubuntu lxc container?

I tried mounting the folder on the host:

```
sudo mount --bind /media/data/share /media/data/container/name/rootfs/share
```

but I can't see any files.

The same goes for:

```
sudo ln -s /media/data/share /media/data/container/name/rootfs/share
```

Do I need to change permissions for the share folder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found an article in the openSUSE wiki: https://en.opensuse.org/User:Tsu2/LXC_mount_shared_directory

I followed the steps and it works now.

Create host directory:

```
mkdir /media/data/share && chmod 7777 /media/data/share
```

Create directory in lxc container:

```
mkdir /share
```

Edit lxc config file on host:

```
nano /var/lib/lxc/containername/config
lxc.mount.entry = /media/data/share share none ro,bind 0.0
```

Comment: Is there a reason behind defining that mount entry as read only? Is that a good security practice to avoid a container to write back data to a shared filesystem?.

Comment: Worked for me. Note that the relative path used for `share` in the `lxc.mount.entry` is critical.

Comment: You don't need to create the mount point, if you add ',create=dir' after 'bind'. I've also removed the 'ro,' part, and it seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 16):

According to the [LXC documentation](https://github.com/lxc/lxd#can-i-bind-mount-my-home-directory-in-a-container) you can do this via a privileged container:

```
lxc launch ubuntu priv -c security.privileged=true
lxc config device add priv homedir disk source=/home/$USER path=/home/ubuntu
```

Comment: Note that, that is the LXD documentation, not LXC. If you haven't installed LXD, then the lxc command won't work.

Comment: @SamBull well, this is self-inflicted by the LXC/LXD team. LXC can be used to refer to liblxc (the underlying library) or to the LXD client (named `lxd`) as used in this answer or to LXC (the software and "old" toolset with the `lxc-*`-named tools) or to the project (where LXC is short for LinuX Containers). It's the reason I asked [this question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4694/5462) on the Unix.SE meta.

Comment: The above requires a privileged container, but for better security separation, you can instead use `lxc config device ... shift=true` and then, if you get the "isn't supported error", `sudo snap set lxd shiftfs.enable=true && sudo systemctl reload snap.lxd.daemon` and retry `lxc config ...`.

Comment: @bitinerant Feel free to just submit an edit to my answer to make it correct, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Below is what I have done to mount one of my host directory to the container. This is trickier than it sounds because we would like to achieve

- Inside the container we should be able to write to the directory.
- Outside the container we should be able to write to the files and directories created inside the container.

After reading various articles online (the most helpful one is [this github issue](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/1879)), here is how I solve this. The trick is to map the uid and gid of the host user to the uid and gid of the user inside the container.

Suppose I am going to mount `/home/breakds/projects` to the exact same location in the container. The outside directory is owned by the user `breakds`, whose uid and gid are `1000`.

I then created an user in the container called `debian`, whose uid and gid happened to be `1000` as well (because it is the first non root user). I will then create an (lxc) profie on the host by

```
lxc profile edit breakds
```

And below is the content of the profile (I believe it is in yaml format):

```
name: breakds
config:
    raw.lxc: |
        lxc.id_map =
        lxc.id_map = u 0 165536 999
        lxc.id_map = g 0 165536 999
        lxc.id_map = u 1000 1000 1
        lxc.id_map = g 1000 1000 1
        lxc.id_map = u 1001 166537 64535
        lxc.id_map = g 1001 166537 64535
    user.vendor-data: |
        packages:
            - bash
description: allow home dir mounting for breakds
devices:
eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
projects:
    path: /home/breakds/projects
    source: /home/debian/projects
    type: disk
```

Then, apply this profile to that container permanently:

```
$ lxc profile apply <my container> breakds
```

This should do the trick.

**NOTE**: Please note that before switching to this profile, make sure that all direcotries or files whose owner/group is debian should be deleted (and probably recreated after the switch). This is because after the uid and gid mapping, their ownership will become invalid. I originally thought since I am just mapping 1000 to 1000 everything should be fine, but I think I missed something here and it would be great if some one can advice on how to resolve this without the hack.

Comment: But you can always `chown` from host.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without LXD by editing the LXC config file directly:

```
# Container specific configuration
lxc.idmap = u 0 165536 1000
lxc.idmap = g 0 165536 1000
lxc.idmap = u 1000 1000 1
lxc.idmap = g 1000 1000 1
lxc.idmap = u 1001 166536 64535
lxc.idmap = g 1001 166536 64535
```

You also have to make sure that the container's user's account is given permission to map to uid/gid 1000 on the host by editing /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid:

```
containeruser:165536:65536
containeruser:1000:1
```

Comment: what system processes/created /etc/subuid? Openwrt does not have that.

Comment: What is the path name of the LXC configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

A more secure way, for an unprivileged container that has access to the host user's files (but not the root user). We create a map from host user to the default lxc user.

```
lxc launch ubuntu:22.04 mycontainer -c raw.idmap="both 1000 1000"
```

The first id is the host user's uid, which is usually 1000 unless there are multiple users are present in the computer. To check run `id YOUR_USERNAME`. The second id is the lxd default user `ubuntu` which is always 1000.

Now run

```
lxc config device add mycontainer mydiskname disk source=~/path/to/desired/folder path=/home/ubuntu/myfolder
```

`mydiskname` can be any name. The `source` path has to exist (and be accessible by the host user) and will be mirrored to `path` in the lxc.

To access the shell as the `ubuntu` user run

```
lxc exec mycontainer -- su -l ubuntu
```

Comment: Where is the `raw.idmap` configuration option documented?